# Purchase new SSL Certificate before existing one expires

Tags: ssl-certificate

I am currently transferring a new customer onto my virtual private server from their old host. They have an existing SSL certificate but it expires next month so I don't think it is worth the hassle of getting the details from the old host.

Would there be any issue with purchasing a new SSL (even if it's from the same authority) whilst they have an existing, unexpired, SSL?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can just request a new certificate, and run both certificates at the same time.
In fact this is quite common for applications that need to be allowed to run without downtime, that require new certificates.

If you install both on one server, the old certificate will be ignored, in favor of the new one.
[Datasprings](http://www.datasprings.com/resources/dnn-tutorials/artmid/535/articleid/68/secure-data-ssl-certificates-part-2?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) has a nice write-up about certificate renewal.

Answer (score 5):

Some CAs, I know DigiCert is one, will carry over the remaining time on your existing cert to the new one.

If you're using such a CA, then just go ahead and request the new certificate.

If you're not, then the only issue that would arise is that you paid twice for the left over time. There are no technical issues to take into account.